# Accessing index of element in array with strings, but string is randomly chosen

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

Im making a text-adventure game where you have to solve riddles. And i created an array `riddles = ["riddle1", "riddle2", ...]` and `answers= ["answer1", "answer2", ...]`(answer1 is answer to riddle1) then i choose random riddle with `riddle = random.choice(riddles)`
and now i have check if `input` is same as the `answer` of the randomly chosen riddle. But first i try to save the correct answer of randomly chosen riddle into variable `answer`. I do that with `answer = answers[riddle]`. I also tried `answer = answers['riddle']` as i found on Google. I even tried `answer = answers[riddles[riddle]]` and i cant get the effect i want

Also i get this error `list indices must be integers or slices, not str` when i try to run the program

Here is the function

`def riddle_room1():

```
riddles=["What has six faces, but does not wear makeup, has twenty-one eyes, but cannot see? What is it?", 
         "I am not alive, but I grow; I don't have lungs, but I need air; I don't have a mouth, but water kills me. What am I?",
        "What runs around the whole yard without moving?",
       "I am something people love or hate. I change peoples appearances and thoughts. If a person takes care of them self I will go up even higher. To some people I will fool them. To others I am a mystery. Some people might want to try and hide me but I will show. No matter how hard people try I will Never go down. What am I?"]
answers=["dice", "fire", "fence" ,"age"]

riddle = random.choice(riddles)
answer = answers[riddles[riddle]]
print(riddle)


guess = input("Your guess: ")

if guess == answer:
    print("Success, you can go forward. Which doors do you pick next (l or r)")
    answer = input(">").lower()
    if "r" in answer:
        riddle_room2()
    elif "l" in answer:
        safe_room2()
    else:
        game_over("You were messing around, and now your dead!")`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of choosing a random *element* from the riddles list, how about generating an integer from `0` to length of `riddles`? This way, you can use this integer as index for both `riddles` and `answers`.

Consider this example:

```
rand = random.randint(1, len(riddles)) # Generate a random int from 0 to length of riddles
riddle = riddles[rand]                 # Use this int as index for riddles
answer = answers[rand]                 # Same int can be used as index for answers
print(riddle)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
riddle = random.choice(riddles)
```

Are you sure `riddle` here is an integer?
To use riddle in the following line, it must be an integer. List indices must always be an integer.

```
answer = answers[riddles[riddle]]
```

I think a dictionary would be more useful here.

Comment: Okay thanks, i will try to do it and will come back to let you know what happened

Answer (score 0):

List indexes must be integers.

```
r = random.randint(0,len(riddles))
riddle = riddles [r]
answer = answers [r]
```

Answer (score 0):

you are getting the error because to get something from the list `list[index]` you need to pass the index parameter which shall be an integer. But you are passing a string index which is leading to the error.

now the solution to the next question

to get the index the riddle belongs to you can do

`answer = answers[riddles.index(riddle)]`

the index function tells the index number of the given parameter(parameter is the thing that you give in the brackets of the functions!)

ex:

```py
strs = ['hello','bye','welcome']
print(strs.index('bye')) #this will print 1 as strs[1] is bye
```

hopefully you got your answer and if there is any doubt you can comment.